# preview html files in google drive without making them public

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I have a bunch of html files in my drive and I want to be able to preview them without downloading them to local. I also don't want to create a public folder and store them there. Basically I want the files to be only visible to me and to people whom I share with. Is it possible?
I don't have to necessarily view the pages in the drive.google.com, it's ok to be a url which has to be accessed outside of drive.google.com, and I can bookmark that url to visit the html files and send the link to authorized people.

I came across this solution in SO but it suggests to create a public folder. 
[opening html from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776324/opening-html-from-google-drive)