# Digital watch html code doesn't work after hosting on google drive

Tags: html

This is my code:

```
<center>
<div style="text-align:center;width:350px;padding:0.5em 0;"> 
<h2><a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/country/bd"><span style="color:gray;"></span><br /></a>
</h2> 
<iframe src="http://www.zeitverschiebung.net/clock-widget-iframe?language=en&timezone=Asia%2FDhaka" width="100%" height="130" frameborder="0" seamless>
</iframe> <small style="color:gray;">
<a href="http://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/" style="color: gray;">
</a>
</small> 
</div>
</center>
```

When I run this code from notepad++ on any browser then it works, but after hosting on google drive it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely problem in content type which  google drive server attach to response it' **not text/html**, which is required for browser to understand that http response body shall be rendered as html, as result of that it simply render html as raw text within browser tab.

Take a look on [opening html from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776324/opening-html-from-google-drive). I am sure you will fin out how to fix your problem in that SO Question.

Good Luck.